# when i clicked on add to cart button it first check "is user login??" then execute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, local-storage, shopping-cart

when i clicked on Add to cart button , it first chek that user login or not if login then continue otherwise redirect to login page

```
$('.divpr').on('click', 'button.cart' ,function () {
    var idstr = this.id.toString();
     
    
    if (cart[idstr] != undefined) {
      console.log("exist");
      cart[idstr][0] = cart[idstr][0] + 1;
      cart[idstr][4]=cart[idstr][4]+cart[idstr][3]
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      
    } else {
      qty = 1;
     
     
     price = document.getElementById('price' + idstr).innerHTML;
      totalPrice=document.getElementById('price' + idstr).innerHTML;
      image = document.getElementById('img' + idstr).src;
      aname = document.getElementById('name' + idstr).innerHTML;
      console.log("not");
      cart[idstr] = [qty, aname, image, parseInt(price),parseInt(totalPrice)];
    }
   
    
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    
    console.log(cart)
  });
```

[it add item to cart even i am not login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXZuu.png)

i want it redirect when i am not loggedin

Comment: Add more context here. What is your app doing and what it is supposed to do

Comment: my app add items of cart in local storage without knowing the user . i want to store cart data of every user separate so that data can never mixup of all users. whenever user clicked on add to cart first of all it checks is user login or not? then store cart data of every user separate